# 400 Bad request while jest testing a POST request to fetch the data

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I am currently working on a node js app where I wrote one of the API using a POST request to fetch the data from the DB. I have used POST req as I didn't want to expose the params in the URL and sending the where clause in the request body of a post request.

I am currently writing the test cases using jest for the post API but getting a bad request error.
Here's my code -

```
'use strict'

jest.mock('../../utils/db2.js')
const request = require('supertest')

const app = require('../../app')


describe('service read API test', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetModules()
  })
  it('service read API good', async () => {
    const res = await request(app)
      .post('/api/v1/abc/xyz/')
      .send({
        id: '090703'
      })
    console.log('Response Body :', JSON.stringify(res.body, null, 2))
    expect(res.status).toBe(200)
    expect(res.body).toEqual({
      dnum: '090703',
      num: 1,
      startdate: '2021-06-01',
      enddate: '2022-05-31',
      rolecode: 5,
      fnum: 1.049,
      lastmodifieddate: '2021-06-02 05:34:04.382279',
      createtime: '2021-06-01 10:53:24.269686',
    })
  })
```

Basically in the API, in the request body, I am sending id and in the response body, I get the result set based on the id provided.
But I keep getting below error -

```
  ● Console

    console.log
      Response Body : {
        "message": "No Records found for the given attributes"
      }

 service read API test › service read API good

    expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: 200
    Received: 400

      46 |       })
      47 |     console.log('Response Body :', JSON.stringify(res.body, null, 2))
    > 48 |     expect(res.status).toBe(200)
         |                        ^
      49 |     expect(res.body).toEqual({
      50 |       dnum: '090703',
      51 |       num: 1,
```

I have tried various things but not sure what am I doing wrong here. Any suggestion?

Controller code below -

```
'use strict'

const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const { getDBDetails } = require('../utils/constants')
const executeDb2Query = require('../utils/db2')
const { validate } = require('express-validation')

router.post('/', async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    if (req.body.constructor === Object && Object.keys(req.body).length === 0) {
      return res.status(400).send('Request Body is empty. Please check!!')
    }
    const request= req.body
    const getDetails = await executeDb2Query({
      sql: getDBDetails(disNum),
      log: req.log,
      name: 'Get Details',
      errorMsg: 'Get error while getting the Details '
    })

    
      return res.status(200).json(getDetails)
    } else {
      return res
        .status(400)
        .json({ message: 'No Records found for the given attributes' })
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return next(error)
  }
})
```

Comment: Please provide the controller code for path `/api/v1/abc/xyz/`. We don't know what happens in the controller.

Comment: Hey - I have added the controller code. Basically I am passing in the details in the request body and based on it, I am running a query from the db and storing it in getDetails and giving the response body.